# pySpark dict (key, value,value)

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

PySpark error when using `when` with dataframes

**pySpark attempt**

```
test = filterDomainLookup.when((col("PrimaryLookupAttributeName") == "") & (col("SecondaryLookupAttributeName") == ""), "Not Defined")
display(test)


AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'when'
```

Comment: I think you just need a code of `when(cond, new_val).otherwise(old_val)`

Comment: @jxc, so you're suggesting creating variables for cond, new val, and old val? I was working on making it work with  `test_d = final_reference.agg(collect_set(array(concat_ws('\0','PrimaryLookupAttributeName', 'SecondaryLookupAttributeName'), 'DomainName')).alias('m')).first().m` and then if c is null then etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, when

cond = col('PrimaryLookupAttributeName').isNull() & col('SecondaryLookupAttributeName').isNull()
# or in your example:
# (col("PrimaryLookupAttributeName") == "") & (col("SecondaryLookupAttributeName") == "")

df1 = filterDomainLookup \
    .withColumn('OutputItemIdByValue', when(cond, lit('4')).otherwise(col('OutputItemIdByValue'))) \
    .withColumn('OutputItemCodeByValue', when(cond, lit('N/D')).otherwise(col('OutputItemCodeByValue'))) \
    .withColumn('OutputItemNameByValue', when(cond, lit('Not Defined')).otherwise(col('OutputItemNameByValue'))) 

df1.select('DomainName', 'PrimaryLookupAttributeName', *[c for c in filterDomainLookup.columns if c.startswith('Out')]).show()
#+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
#|       DomainName|PrimaryLookupAttributeName|OutputItemIdByValue|OutputItemCodeByValue|OutputItemNameByValue|
#+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
#|LeaseRecoveryType|                      null|                  4|                  N/D|          Not Defined|
#|LeaseRecoveryType|         LeaseRecoveryType|                 11|                 null|                Gross|
#|LeaseRecoveryType|         LeaseRecoveryType|                 18|                 null|       Modified Gross|
#|      LeaseStatus|               LeaseStatus|                 10|                 null|               Active|
#|      LeaseStatus|               LeaseStatus|                 10|                 null|           Terminated|
#|      LeaseStatus|               LeaseStatus|                 11|                 null|              Expired|
#|      LeaseStatus|               LeaseStatus|                 10|                 null|              Pending|
#+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Update:** as discussed from another post, when ItemID, ItemCode and ItemName are retrieved from default_reference, create a mapping between ItemId to ItemName and ItemCode:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set, array

default_reference.show()                                                                                           
+--------+----------+------+--------+--------------------+
|DomainId|DomainName|ItemId|ItemCode|            ItemName|
+--------+----------+------+--------+--------------------+
|       0|   Default|     0|     N/S|Not Specified at ...|
|       0|   Default|     1|     N/F|    Lookup Not Found|
|       0|   Default|     2|     N/I|Not Implemented i...|
|       0|   Default|     3|     N/A|      Not Applicable|
|       0|   Default|     4|     N/D|         Not Defined|
|       0|   Default|     5|     O/R|   Consumer Override|
|       0|   Default|     6|     SCM|Standard Column M...|
+--------+----------+------+--------+--------------------+

map_ids = dict((int(e[0]), {'code':e[1],'name':e[2]}) for e in default_reference.agg(collect_set(array('ItemId','ItemCode','ItemName')).alias('id')).first().id) 
#map_ids
#{'6': {'code': 'SCM', 'name': 'Standard Column M...'},
# '2': {'code': 'N/I', 'name': 'Not Implemented i...'},
# '4': {'code': 'N/D', 'name': 'Not Defined'},
# '3': {'code': 'N/A', 'name': 'Not Applicable'},
# '1': {'code': 'N/F', 'name': 'Lookup Not Found'},
# '0': {'code': 'N/S', 'name': 'Not Specified at ...'},
# '5': {'code': 'O/R', 'name': 'Consumer Override'}}

cond = col('PrimaryLookupAttributeName').isNull() & col('SecondaryLookupAttributeName').isNull()

item_id = 4
item = map_ids[item_id]

NotDefined_filterDomainLookup = filterDomainLookup \
    .filter(cond) \
    .withColumn('OutputItemIdByValue', lit(item_id)) \
    .withColumn('OutputItemCodeByValue', lit(item['code'])) \
    .withColumn('OutputItemNameByValue', lit(item['name']))
```

Comment: my attempt was the following` #test = filterDomainLookup.withColumn("PrimaryLookupAttributeName", f.when((col("PrimaryLookupAttributeName").isNull() & (col("SecondaryLookupAttributeName").isNull()), "Not Defined")))` but it error out, which makes sense. Your solution works! thank you! makes perfect sensse @jxc

Comment: actually, I'm trying to create mappings similar to another code you suggested: `testing_map_key = concat_ws('\0', filterDomainLookup.DomainName, filterDomainLookup.PrimaryLookupAttributeName) testing_map_value = filterDomainLookup.OutputItemIdByAttribute testing = filterDomainLookup.agg(collect_set(array(concat_ws('\0','DomainName','PrimaryLookupAttributeName'), 'OutputItemIdByAttribute')).alias('id')).first().id` but get `ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring. `OutputItemIdByAttribute` is **int** type @jxc

Comment: @jgtrz can you change `'OutputItemIdByAttribute'` to `col('OutputItemIdByAttribute').astype('string')` in the `agg()` method call. I am not able to reproduce your error though. just cast it to `string`, so the data type matches with the first array item.

Comment: poking your brain with new questions.I updated my post. I have learned a lot! @jxc

Comment: This looks like a very different question, can u open a new question and I will check it back when I get home in about 1 hour

Comment: absolutely! I'll into reversing the changes to the original question. New question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053976/pyspark-iterating-repetitive-variables @jxc, thank you in advance!

Comment: now if  I want to make it conditional as in if `cond` results in nothing, then do nothing. IF `cond` contains something, then `NotDefined_filterDomainLookup`. what type is `cond`, I'm trying to print it but get `'Column' object is not callable` @jxc

Comment: @jgtrz, `cond` is a Column object, it returns `Column<b'((PrimaryLookupAttributeName IS NULL) AND (PrimaryLookupAttributeName IS NULL))'>`. you can remove otherwise() if you want to set NULL to non-matches.

Comment: is there a way to quantify `cond`? or a way to only execute `NotDefined_filterDomainLookup` if `cond` has something? @jxc

Comment: that will be much simpler, will update the post next.