# pySpark iterating repetitive variables

Tags: loops, pyspark

I have a code that currently works, however I'm looking to make it more efficient and avoid hard coding:

1) avoid hard coding: for `NotDefined_filterDomainLookup`  will like to reference the **default_reference** df for the corresponding Code and Name when Id = 4. Instead of hard coding the Code and Name value.

**Question 1**

**list of columns name and corresponding new column names**

```
test_matchedAttributeName_List =dict(matchedDomains.agg(collect_set(array('DomainName', 'TargetAttributeForName')).alias('m')).first().m)

Output: {'LeaseType': 'ConformedLeaseTypeName', 'LeaseRecoveryType': 'ConformedLeaseRecoveryTypeName', 'LeaseStatus': 'ConformedLeaseStatusName'}
```

**working code, except looking to avoid hard coding. Specifically, I will like to reference the default_reference df for the corresponding Code and Name when Id = 4**

```
cond = col('PrimaryLookupAttributeName').isNull() & col('SecondaryLookupAttributeName').isNull()

NotDefined_filterDomainLookup = filterDomainLookup \
    .withColumn('OutputItemIdByAttribute', when(cond, lit('4')).otherwise(col('OutputItemIdByAttribute'))) \
    .withColumn('OutputItemCodeByAttribute', when(cond, lit('N/D')).otherwise(col('OutputItemCodeByAttribute'))) \
    .withColumn('OutputItemNameByAttribute', when(cond, lit('Not Defined')).otherwise(col('OutputItemNameByAttribute')))
```

------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------

Comment: How can we link `default_reference.ItemId` with the other data? how do we know which itemID should be applied when filling null values? does the default_reference containing other Rows having DomainName != 'Default'?

Comment: @jxc, using DomainName would not work.  I think, it can be broken down in 2 steps? 1) identified `cond` and link `NotDefined_filterDomainLookup` to Id=4, N/D, etc. Hard Coding Id=4 mapped to `filterDomainLookup.OutputItemCodeByAttribute =  default_reference.ItemCode` ?and then step 2. I updated the post

Comment: so, for Q-1, you just want to automatically find `ItemCode` and `ItemName` by giving an ItemId, the mapping comes from `default_reference`? in your example, you have id=4 and thus `N/D` and `Not defined` should be retrieved from mapping?

Comment: @jxc, yes, exactly. Said in much simpler words ..

Comment: @jxc, &  `NotDefined_filterDomainLookup` will only deal with Id=4 since it should only act when `cond` is applicable. I think the `.otherwise` is irrelevant in this case

Comment: @jxc, I'm looking into regexp_extract

Comment: I think Q-1 is close related to the previous question, I will update there and will check Q-2 after Q-1.

Comment: for Q-2, I don't think it's useful to define `<..>_map_key` and `<>_map_value`, those variables are used for illustration purpose,, not actually used in the code.

Comment: @jxc, got it. That should clean it up a little bit, but helped me understand the logic. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Question-2, based on your code, I'd advise some adjustments as below:

- Set up *item_keys* including *Id*, *Name* and *Code* and merge the same logic using list comprehensions
- Use *struct* instead of *array* to implement the above logic
- No need to create Python dictionary for *NotDefned_Attribute_List*, list of tuples are enough and better

See below steps:

(1) Set up two aggregate functions to calculate *item_map* used for *testing_mappings* and *NotDefined_Attribute_List*. check [named_struct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#named_struct) and [struct](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct) (two methods for the same task for your exercises)

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, collect_set, struct, col

item_keys = ['Id', 'Name', 'Code']

# use SQL expression
m1_by_sql_expr = expr("""
  collect_set(
    named_struct(
      'attr_name', PrimaryLookupAttributeName,
      'attr_value', PrimaryLookupAttributeValue,
      'Id', OutputItemIdByValue,
      'Name', OutputItemNameByValue,
      'Code', OutputItemCodeByValue
    )
  ) as item_map
""")

# use PySpark API functions
m2_by_func = collect_set(
    struct(
      col('DomainName').alias('domain'),
      col('TargetAttributeForId').alias('Id'),
      col('TargetAttributeForName').alias('Name'),
      col('TargetAttributeForCode').alias('Code')
    )
  ).alias('item_map')
```

(2) Set up *ItemKey*(*Id*, *Code* or *Name*) + *PrimaryLookupAttributeName* + *PrimaryLookupAttributeValue* mapping to *ItemValue*

```
  m1 = NotDefined_filterDomainLookup.agg(m1_by_sql_expr).first().item_map

  """create a list of tuples of (map_key, map_value) to create MapType column:
     | map_key = concat_ws('\0', item_key, attr_name, attr_value)
     | map_value = item_value
  """
  testingId = [('\0'.join([k, row.attr_name, row.attr_value]), row[k]) for row in m1 for k in item_keys if row[k]]
  #[('Id\x00LeaseRecoveryType\x00Gross w/base year', '18'),
  # ('Name\x00LeaseRecoveryType\x00Gross w/base year', 'Modified Gross'),
  # ('Id\x00LeaseStatus\x00Abandoned', '10'),
  # ('Name\x00LeaseStatus\x00Abandoned', 'Active'),
  # ('Id\x00LeaseStatus\x00Draft', '10'),
  # ('Name\x00LeaseStatus\x00Draft', 'Pending'),
  # ('Id\x00LeaseStatus\x00Archive', '11'),
  # ('Name\x00LeaseStatus\x00Archive', 'Expired'),
  # ('Id\x00LeaseStatus\x00Terminated', '10'),
  # ('Name\x00LeaseStatus\x00Terminated', 'Terminated'),
  # ('Id\x00LeaseRecoveryType\x00Gross', '11'),
  # ('Name\x00LeaseRecoveryType\x00Gross', 'Gross'),
  # ('Id\x00LeaseRecoveryType\x00Gross-modified', '15'),
  # ('Name\x00LeaseRecoveryType\x00Gross-modified', 'Modified Gross')]

  # this could be a problem for too many entries.
  testing_mappings = create_map([lit(i) for i in chain.from_iterable(testingId)])
```

(3) Create *NotDefined_AttributeCode_List* (same logic as in (2), use PySpark API functions for m2)

```
  m2 = matchedDomains.agg(m2_by_func).first().item_map

  NotDefned_Attribute_List = [(k, row.domain, row[k]) for row in m2 for k in item_keys if row[k]]
```

(4) Get a list of additional columns based on *NotDefined_Attribute_List*:

```
  additional_cols = [
    testing_mappings[concat_ws('\0', lit(k), lit(c), col(c))].alias(c_name)
      for k,c,c_name in NotDefined_Attribute_List
  ]
```

(5) select the additional columns

```
if count_ND > 0: 

  # move code above in (2), (3) and (4) here

  # set up testing_NotDefined
  testing_NotDefined = datasetMatchedPortfolio.select("*", *additional_cols)

else:
  print("no Not Defines exist")
```

Comment: change the order of `item_keys` and `m2` if you want to sort NotDefned_Attribute_List by item_keys first: `NotDefned_Attribute_List = [(k, row.domain, row[k]) for k in item_keys for row in m2 if row[k]]`

Comment: I would need to digest this and understand named_struct and struct. I'll follow up, thank you!

Comment: can you explain Step 3 (`NotDefned_Attribute_List = [(k, row.domain, row[k]) ..`)